# ASP.MVC Beta Install Problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've just downloaded the ASP.MVC MSI package, but the installation fails with the "**There is a problem with this Windows Installer Package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor.**" message.

I see that other people too have the same problem (http://forums.asp.net/p/1336453/2699267.aspx). Anybody else?

I'm running VS 2008 Professional edition with SP1 on Vista.

Some additional info: entries like **Error in Template (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\VisualBasic\Workflow\1033\StateMachineWorkflowLibrary.zip), file (StateMachineWorkflowLibrary.vstemplate).  Unregistered ProjectType (VisualBasic).  This can be caused by an incorrect ProjectType or because the project type package is not installed.** appear in the event log.

BTW I don't have VisualBasic installed. I'm thinking about reinstalling VisualStudio ... :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed all the bad templates and this didn't resolve the issue for me. I found that removing other Add-Ins I had installed let me install Beta 1. In my case the bad add-in preventing the install was [Clone Detective](http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS).

Comment: Simon, I have the same feeling - Clone Detective already did mess up some other stuff in VisualStudio.

Comment: I verified this (uninstalled CD; I do not, and still do not, have VB installed) and posted an issue to CD's [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=11549) site

Comment: Uninstalling Clone Detective also allowed me to uninstall the ASP.Net MVC Beta.

Comment: Clone Detective was blocking it for me; removing it allowed me to install ASP.NET MVC v1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error message from a completely different MSI package - the DevExpress toolkit - turned out to be caused by one of the "defensive" packages installed on my machine.

Check your anti-virus, anti-spyware, anti-intrusion, firewall, anti-xxx etc etc packages to see if any of them might be stopping scripts from running properly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The installer is trying to add templates to the VB package without checking to see if it exists first (ScottGuuuuuuu!).

If the rest of MVC is installed and working, forget about it.  If not, you don't have to reinstall VS.  A quick fix is to simply install Visual Basic (e.g, modify your installation rather than reinstall it).

Comment: A colleague of mine installed MVC without problems on his VS without Visual Basic, so I don't think this is an issue. Anyway, the actual VB templates do exist on the disk.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, like Simon said, [Clone Detective](http://www.codeplex.com/CloneDetectiveVS) addin was the troublemaker which prevented the installation of ASP MVC. I deinstalled Clone Detective and now MVC has installed without problems. Thanks guys!