# ASP.NET MVC fails at install

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation

I need some help on asp.net mvc install.

I got the below two errors when I try to install ASP.NET MVC Beta:

*Faulting application devenv.exe, version 9.0.21022.8, time stamp 0x47317b3d, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x006c0061, process id 0x11d8, application start time 0x01c949b7447a7a50.*

*Product: Microsoft ASP.NET MVC Beta -- Error 1722. There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program run as part of the setup did not finish as expected. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action VisualStudio_VSSetup_Command, location: D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0v2\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe, command: /setup*

I uninstalled and then installed Visual Studio but nothing changed.

I have the following configuration: 
Visual Studio 2008 sp1, 
.net 3.5 sp1, 
Windows Server 2008

Does anyone has a solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228997/aspmvc-beta-install-problems

Answer (score 0):

have you tried rebooting your machine then trying again?

have you tried re-downloading the installer and trying again?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded the installer again and I restarted my pc. 

Note: ASP.NET MVC Preveiw 5 works ok.